# Regex to scan for a specific number of a repeating character

Tags: javascript

First time using regex I am having a little bit of trouble formatting to select a specific count of `}`

I want to be able to eliminate for example `}}}` but should still pick up `}}`.

I have this so far

```
/^(?!\||}}})(([A-Za-z0-9\s:,']|{{{|{{|}}|{:|:}|)+)/
```

however this way in the event of `x}}}` it will match `x}}` when I need to match `x` only. while if I submit `x}}` the return should be `x}}`.

Sample input:

example 1: `x}}}` output: `x`.

example 2: `x}}`  output: `x}}`

Comment: please provide a sample text to format.

Comment: I did as an example given "x}}}" only "x" should match given "x}}" the entire "x}}" needs to match but in "x}}}" the match should not say "x}}"

Comment: [Negative lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)?

Comment: as stated above I have negative lookahead the problem is that for my example it still recognizes `x}}`

Comment: Also, what is the context for this? What is the larger problem this is helping to solve?

Comment: If you want to be able to search for just two characters, why not just use `\}{2}` ?

Comment: I have to code a parser that finds tokens in a given string `}}}` and `}}` are distinct tokens and `}}` should not be found within `}}}`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show some sample input strings with their corresponding desired outputs.

Comment: How about this? `/x(?:}}(?!}))?/` (`x}}` -> `x}}`, `x}}}` -> `x`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try this:

```
/((?!\})[^\}\{]*(?=\}{3}[^\}]?))|((?!\})[^\}\{]*\}{2}(?=[^\}]?))/g
```

```js
var str = "{{{x}}{{x1}}{{x2}}}";
var regxPat = /((?!\})[^\}\{]*(?=\}{3}[^\}]?))|((?!\})[^\}\{]*\}{2}(?=[^\}]?))/g;
var matchResult = str.match(regxPat);

console.log(matchResult);
```

Comment: not sure I am quite following the syntax here why a boolean? using http://regexr.com it is not matching anything

Comment: @user12345 you might want to try it again.

Comment: using exec it wasn't working but with match it works perfectly thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

`/[{]*([^{}]}}([^}]|$)|[^{}]*)[}]*/`

This captures your test result in its first capture group.

---

**Example:**

```js
let regex = /[{]*([^{}]}}([^}]|$)|[^{}]*)[}]*/
console.info('{{{x}}}'.match(regex)[1])
console.info('x}}}'.match(regex)[1])
console.info('x}}'.match(regex)[1])
```

<sup>Note: I do not condone using regex for this specific use case. It is not a good tool to use for snagging contents of possibly recursive template strings.</sup>

Comment: @user12345 - I added your use cases and it works. With match, you must use ordinal 1 to get the first capture in the match.

Comment: Updated to match your second example.

Comment: Using both http://regexr.com  I am matching all of the string could this be because you are doing .match not .exec?

Comment: You need to select the capture group. You can see I'm selecting the first one in my example where I print to console. You can try the same code in my example in your browsers console to verify it works.

Comment: isn't the capture group defined by whatever string you submit, in this case `{{{x}}}` and `x}}}` and `x}}`. I don't really understand the syntax you are using what is the `[1]` modifier at the end?

Comment: Match returns an array, index 0 is the full match, index 1 is the first capture, index 2 the second capture and so on. [1] is how you access index 1 of the array (the first capture group).